# Android Studio make status bar background complete transparent and change icon color

Tags: android, statusbar, android-statusbar

i need to make the status bar transparent, and change the icon color to a darker grey. Because i am using a viewpager and the layout must go below the status bar, i also tried it with

```
 "windowTranslucentStatus=true"
```

But with it i cant change the color of status bar and it wasn't transparent, it was a darker grey and light transparent. And i want to change the color of the status bar in the layout when it is transparent. So i can create on the top of my layout, a view that has a height of 25dp and can change there the color, and when i am swiping, the color on the status bar should swiping too.
If im not doing this it look very terrible.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this for status bar

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Works with ActionBarActivity.